# Переделать алгоритм Беллмана-Форда так, чтобы он выводил не длины путей в графе, а сами пути

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

У меня есть алгоритм Беллмана-Форда на Python. Никак не соображу, как восстановить и вывести путь. __AdjList - список смежности. __amount - размерность графа.

```
    def BellmanFord(self, src):
    INF = 10 ** 9

    dist = dict.fromkeys(self.__AdjList.keys(), INF)
    dist[src] = 0
    visited = dict.fromkeys(self.__AdjList.keys(), INF)
    for i in range(self.__amount - 1):

        for u in self.__AdjList.keys():
            for v in self.__AdjList[u].keys():
                w = self.__AdjList[u][v]
                if dist[u] != INF and int(dist[u]) + int(w) < int(dist[v]):
                    dist[v] = int(dist[u]) + int(w)

    for u in self.__AdjList.keys():
        for v in self.__AdjList[u].keys():
            w = self.__AdjList[u][v]
            # if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
            if dist[u] != INF and int(dist[u]) + int(w) < int(dist[v]):
                return 'Graph contains negative weight cycle'

    for x in list(dist.keys()):
        if x in dist and dist[x] == INF:
            dist.pop(x)
    return dist
```

Edited:

```
 def BellmanFord(self, src, b):
    INF = 10 ** 9

    dist = dict.fromkeys(self.__AdjList.keys(), INF)
    dist[src] = 0
    pred = list()
    for i in range(self.__amount - 1):

        for u in self.__AdjList.keys():
            for v in self.__AdjList[u].keys():
                w = self.__AdjList[u][v]
                if dist[u] != INF and int(dist[u]) + int(w) < int(dist[v]):
                    dist[v] = int(dist[u]) + int(w)
                    pred[v] = u

    for u in self.__AdjList.keys():
        for v in self.__AdjList[u].keys():
            w = self.__AdjList[u][v]
            # if dist[u] != float("Inf") and dist[u] + w < dist[v]:
            if dist[u] != INF and int(dist[u]) + int(w) < int(dist[v]):
                return 'Graph contains negative weight cycle'

    for x in list(dist.keys()):
        if x in dist and dist[x] == INF:
            dist.pop(x)

    path = [b]
    temp = b
    while temp != src:
        temp = pred[temp]
        path.append(temp)
    print(path[::-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В том месте, где срабатывает выбор минимума

```
if dist[u] != INF and int(dist[u]) + int(w) < int(dist[v]):
    dist[v] = int(dist[u]) + int(w)
    #тут
```

добавьте запись предка текущей вершины в дополнительный список `pred[]`

```
    pred[v] = u
```

по окончании работы пройдите по предкам от нужной конечной вершины, затем разверните полученный путь

```
path = [target]
temp = target
while temp != src:
    temp = pred[temp]
    path.append(temp) 
print(path[::-1])
```

Comment: Я что-то плохо соображаю. Можете поподробнее описать восстановление пути? Его нужно как отдельный метод использовать или вставить в существующий метод?

Comment: я добавил измененный вариант, посмотрите пожалуйста, правильно ли я понял

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо большое за помощь